# Marking down an arrow in an equation

Tags: equations

How to write this equation in LaTex?

```
$$y_t^s=\underset{\underset{\scriptstyle\text{Output of firms with one year old contracts}{\scriptstyle\downarrow}}{\frac{1}{2}(P_t-w_t(t-1)+u_t)}+\underset{\underset{\scriptstyle\text{Output of firms with two year old contracts}{\scriptstyle\downarrow}}{\frac{1}{2}(P_t-w_t(t-2)+u_t)}$$
```

I wrote this, but couldn't get it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} % For \text{...}
\begin{document}
  {$\arraycolsep=2ex
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \dfrac{1}{2}[P_t - w_t(t-1) + u_t]              & + & \dfrac{1}{2}[P_t-w_t(t-2)+u_t]\\
    \Bigg\downarrow                                 &   & \Bigg\downarrow\\
    \text{\scriptsize Output of firms with workers} &   & \text{\scriptsize Output of firms with workers}\\
    \text{\scriptsize on one-year old contract}     &   & \text{\scriptsize on two-year (expiring) contract}\\
  \end{array}
  $}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my proposal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[y_t=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}[P_t-w_t(t-1)+u_t]}
_{\substack{\text{Output of firms with workers}\\\text{on one-year old contract}}}+
\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}[P_t-w_t(t-2)+u_t]}
_{\substack{\text{Output of firms with workers}\\\text{on two-year (expiring) contract}}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please [do not use `$$` for display equations!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/156344)

Answer (score 3):

A variant with some improvements – in particular medium-size fractions from `nccmath` and the normal spacing for the `+` sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\[ y_t=\underset{\mathclap{\substack{ \rule{0.4pt}{2em}\\ \strut\text{Output of firms with workers}\\\text{on one-year old contract}}}}{\mfrac{1}{2}\bigl[P_t-w_t(t-1)+u_t\bigr]}
+
\underset{\mathclap{\substack{\rule{0.4pt}{2em}\\ \strut\text{Output of firms with workers}\\\text{on two-year (expiring) contract}}}}{\mfrac{1}{2}\bigl[P_t-w_t(t-2)+u_t\bigr]}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

My proposal with the `tag` is this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
y_t=\underset{\underset{\substack{\text{Output of firms with workers} \\ \text{on one-year old contract}}}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[1cm]{}}$}}}{\dfrac{1}{2}[P_t - w_t(t-1) + u_t]}+\underset{\underset{\substack{\text{Output of firms with workers} \\ \text{on two-year (expiring) contract}}}{\rotatebox{-90}{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[1cm]{}}$}}}{\dfrac{1}{2}[P_t-w_t(t-2)+u_t]}
\] 
\end{document}
```

or you could use also `tikz-cd`, used to typeset commutative diagrams and also for other things....

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-.4cm]
{y_t=\dfrac{1}{2}[P_t - w_t(t-1) + u_t]}+ \arrow[d] & {\dfrac{1}{2}[P_t-w_t(t-2)+u_t]} \arrow[d] \\
\substack{\text{Output of firms with workers} \\ \text{on one-year old contract}} & \substack{\text{Output of firms with workers} \\ \text{on two-year (expiring) contract}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
cument}
```